# extracting decimal points from a float number

Tags: javascript

I have a java script that calculates percentage of discount offered. Right now, I am flooring the percentage value

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
for( i = 0; i < prices_monthly.length; i++ ) {
    if( prices_monthly[i] != "N/A" ) {
        var annualNum = prices_annual[i].replace(',','');
    annual_savings_perc[i] = Math.floor( ( ((12*prices_monthly[i])-annualNum)/ (12*prices_monthly[i]) )*100);
    }
}
});
```

I want to enhance this by adding some logic. My needs are this

- If the first 2 decimal points are >97 ( i.e 19.98, 20.99 etc) I want to use ceil (or round function) to round it off next integer. If not, I want to use floor function.

I am not sure how I can get the first 2 decimal points ( 98 in case of 19.98 and 99 in case of 20.99). If I can get that in a variable, I can apply if condition. Or is there a simpler way to do this.
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either make a string and split it:

```
var decimalValue = 19.98,
    result = decimalValue.toString().split('.')[1];

console.log(result);
```

Or use the modulus operator:

```
var decimalValue = 19.98,
    result = decimalValue % 1;

console.log(result);
```

Note that the latter will give you the remainder after division e.g. `0.98`